# Triangle-style sequences

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

Consider the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) and their forward differences:

$$
T = 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, ... \\
\Delta T = 2,3,4,5,6, ...
$$

If we alter \$\Delta T\$ so that it begins with a different integer, we get a different, yet similar sequence (assuming that it begins with \$T'_1 = 1\$):

$$
\Delta T' = 3,4,5,6,7,8,... \\
T' = 1, 4, 8, 13, 19, 26, 34,...
$$

This can be extended to begin with negative numbers:

$$
\Delta T' = -2,-1,0,1,2,3,... \\
T' = 1,-1,-2,-2,-1,1,4,...
$$

More generally, for a given integer \$n\$, we can define a "triangle-style" sequence \$T'\$ as a sequence whose forward differences form the sequence \$n, n+1, n+2, n+3, ...\$, and that has \$1\$ as its first term

---

You should take an integer \$n\$ and do one of:

- Take a positive integer \$m\$ and output the first \$m\$ integers of the "triangle-style" sequence for \$n\$
- Take an integer \$m\$ and output the \$m\$th integer in the "triangle-style" sequence for \$n\$. You may use either 0 or 1 indexing
- Output all integers in the "triangle-style" sequence for \$n\$

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

---

### Test cases

These are the first 10 outputs for each provided \$n\$:

```
 n -> out
-4 -> 1, -3, -6, -8, -9, -9, -8, -6, -3, 1
-3 -> 1, -2, -4, -5, -5, -4, -2, 1, 5, 10
-2 -> 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 4, 8, 13, 19
-1 -> 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28
 0 -> 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29, 37
 1 -> 1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29, 37, 46
 2 -> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55
 3 -> 1, 4, 8, 13, 19, 26, 34, 43, 53, 64
 4 -> 1, 5, 10, 16, 23, 31, 40, 50, 61, 73
39 -> 1, 40, 80, 121, 163, 206, 250, 295, 341, 388
68 -> 1, 69, 138, 208, 279, 351, 424, 498, 573, 649
48 -> 1, 49, 98, 148, 199, 251, 304, 358, 413, 469
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the deltas of the triangular numbers start at 2, not 1.

Comment: Can I output `m+1` integers instead of `m`?

Comment: \$ T^{'}(n, m) = T(n + m - 2) - T(n - 1) + 1 \$. Now if only you had used true 0-indexing starting from \$ T(0) = 0 \$ ...

Comment: @Jonah No, you may not

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Isn't it the equivalent of using 0-indexing, which is allowed for the 2nd option?

Answer (score 13):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 18 bytes

```hs
f n=scanl(+)1[n..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7Y4OTEvR0Nb0zA6T08v9n9uYmaegpWVgqe/goYmF5hnq5CSz6WgUFCUmVeioKJQkpidqmAKZKQpaOiaaGKTAUoZ4BA3wSVu8R8A)

Outputs an infinite list.

```haskell
f n = scanl (+) 1 [n..]
                  [n..]  -- Make an infinite list n, n+1, ...
      scanl (+) 1        -- Cumulative sum, starting at 1
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
Ḷ+S‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm3awY8aZvw3NAAyDy8/vE/XpMjk0BL3/wA)

Takes 0-based \$m\$ and \$n\$, and returns the \$m\$-th term.

#### How it works

```
Ḷ+S‘  Left arg: m, Right arg: n
Ḷ     [0..m-1]
 +    [n..n+m-1]
  S   Sum
   ‘  Increment
```

Comment: Looks like you ninja'd me :p

Comment: Wait, what? Did I somehow miss this? I could've sworn I tried this when going through the like 50 combinations of built-ins I imagined might work...

Answer (score 8):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
ʁ+∑›
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CA%81%2B%E2%88%91%E2%80%BA&inputs=9%0A-4&header=&footer=)

An exact port of Bubbler's jelly answer. Takes `m` as the 0-based index to retrieve and `n` as the variant

### Explained

```
ʁ+∑›
ʁ    # [0 ... m-1]
 +   # ↑ + n (vectorises)
  ∑  # sum(↑)
   › # ↑ + 1 (implicitly output)
```

Comment: no flag abuse \o/ (yes I will keep bullying you about it, no I am not serious)

Comment: jokes on you because I myself try to keep flagless unless neccesary

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 24 bytes

Takes an integer \$n\$ and outputs the \$m\$th integer in the "triangle-style" sequence for \$n\$. Uses 0-indexing.

```python
lambda n,m:~-m*m/2+n*m+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ9eqTjdXK1ffSDtPK1fb8H9afpFCpkJmnkJRYl56qoahgaYVl0JBUWZeiUKahq6JjkKm5n8A)

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda n,m:m*(m+n+n-1)/2+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ9cqV0sjVztPO0/XUFPfSNvwf1p@kUKmQmaeQlFiXnqqhqGBphWXQkFRZl6JQpqGromOQqbmfwA)

Answer (score 7):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 14 bytes

```
1"}
+<
",{
>+1
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiMVwifVxuKzxcblwiLHtcbj4rMSIsInYiOjEsImkiOiItMSJ9)

[image: run for -1]

The lower loop is the increment, that starts with the input `{` and gets increased by one `+1` each iteration. It's get copied `"` into `+`, where the accumulator loops. Every iteration it gets copied into the output `}`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
r+ṖS‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/79I@@HOacGPGmb8//9f1@S/CQA)

Given left argument \$n\$ and right argument \$m\$, output the \$m\$th element of the \$n\$-variant triangular sequence (0-indexed).

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)($i=1)
2..$b|%{($i+=$a++)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLtSsNAEPzdPMUhpzY0keRylw8kUPEBFOs/EUnrqZV@maQoaJ@9zrZ3uaIiZJPb3ZnZ2SSr5buumxc9m4WTZa23/Kn83K6qupr3eRXwsd/n0zL2PXF2xsdfx59IByWvBgN/s9143rDv9YJhP5RBHOEZByxMECkiRxQmclNDL/b9PSVxFIGQCGVC7mtoIYsjyxCOYVlif8YFDqbENKGwhLgjRLsLB/RT0kRAW6AicgOPOjRVd4oZzpSDIlAR2CXJDNyJ/4NFJzV45/4vD6iiJpErZQjuBR3uBjCACUoSuSItaQjuIygjT16ASEgDuUKkOGeJHVG4GejlxBG7JcASEdGJIwpFI8l6bt9WmnfUtCBzOTHoltHmiiQFuSxQU9nOp/0w0nElwISIJd0KWo@oSSRJBDVJa8uUqD7@P693N12097zVTXtZNTpgfI7QHys9afUjKxl/8Hq81s161iI74U@sAwPb9S6aUVtPF8/EMOjwdTldsNOAnQJlFQ9x3ZRD5N316HLdtMv51fgV3fshPPZG68lEN40T72RC/cZ@iZ@DcmtNluzIOQ7h@YjaN3ajH4LobbzN9hs)

Saved two bytes by removing superfluous parentheses

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
L<+O>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx0bb3@7/fxMuXTMA)

05AB1E looks like brainfuck :P

Comment: It fails for \$n=0\$ because the `L` creates the list `[1,0]`. If you change `L<` to `Ý¨` it works as intended, although unfortunately doesn't look like brainfuck anymore. ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [kalker](https://kalker.strct.net/), 26 bytes

Nothing fancy, just bringing attention to [kalker](https://kalker.strct.net/), a lovely command-line calculator that I recently stumbled upon.

```
f(a,b)=Σ(1,b,n)+(b-1)(a-2)
```

An online interpreter can be found [here](https://kalker.strct.net/kalk).

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 9 bytes

```
{1+/x+!y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqtpQW79CW7Gy9n@agp66uq6Jgq6xgq6Rgq6hgoGCoYKRgrGCiY6@VYyVoqHBfwA)

Takes `n` as `x`, and `m` as `y`; outputs the m-th integer in the "triangle-style" sequence for n (0-indexed). Feels like there is a more clever way, but...

- `x+!y` generate `n..n+m-1`
- `1+/` take the sum (seeded with 1)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 44 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,m,a=1:m and[a]+f(n+1,m-1,n+a)or[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802JzE3KSVRIU8nVyfR1tAqVyExLyU6MVY7TSNP21AnV9dQJ087UTO/KDr2f0FRZl6JRpqGromOmaYmF4xrgMJDlTOxAHH/AwA)

```python
f=lambda n,m,a=1:m and[a]+f(n+1,m-1,n+a)or[]
             a=1                             #Set accumulator to 1 initially
                 m and                       #If m>0
                      [a]+f(n+1,m-1,n+a)     #Prepend accumulator to the rest of
                                             #Every time, the accumulator increases by
                                             #the current n
                                             #the sequence
                                        or[] #Otherwise, return an empty list
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 19 bytes

```javascript
n=>m=>m--*(m/2+n)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i4XiHR1tTRy9Y208zS1Df8n5@cV5@ek6uXkp2ukaeiaaGqYaWr@BwA)

-5 bytes thanks to Bubbler, tsh and ophact

Comment: You can omit `f=` from byte count since it's not recursive, and `n=>m=>` is one byte shorter than `(n,m)=>`.

Comment: `(m+n+n-1)/2` -> `((m-1)/2+n)` -> `(--m/2+n)`

Comment: [19](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i4XiHR1tTRy9Y208zS1Df8n5@cV5@ek6uXkp2ukaeiaaGqYaWr@BwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
∫:1¡→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HHaivDQwsftU36//@/iQUA)

an infinite list.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 30 bytes

```powershell
param($m,$n)$m*($m+2*$n-1)/2+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVXRyVPUyVXC8jSNtJSydM11NQ30jb8//@/yX9dMwA)

-1 byte thanks to @Julian

Comment: you can save one char by replacing `$n+$n` with `2*$n`

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
function(n,m)m*(m-1)/2+m*n+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcxLDkAwEADQvVNYzjCNXyMIV7C0l6ZNmpgSKimXr513gHdGM0VzO@Xt7sARI2fAosKizjlzeRXDKBQIOUhqemo7kh0ml/bzyvqCbT2O7YFA6X9YXLTy@2lfDQbBUjn0iJQGjB8)

Outputs `m`th (0-indexed) term.

Using straightforward formula.

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB/Octave, 22 bytes

```matlab
@(n,m)sum([1,n:m+n-2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPJ1ezuDRXI9pQJ88qVztP1yhW83@abWJesTVXmoauiY6hgSaIYQxjGMEYhlCGggGMAReBqVGA6VKAmWNsCWWYWUAZJmDGfwA)
Anonymous function. Outputs `m`th integer of sequence for `n`.

Alternatively, if we want to output all elements from 1st to `m`th we can achieve so with **25 bytes**:

```matlab
@(n,m)cumsum([1,n:m+n-2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPJ1czuTS3uDRXI9pQJ88qVztP1yhW83@abWJesTVXmoauiY6hgSaIYQxjGMEYhlCGggGMAReBqVGA6VKAmWNsCWWYWUAZJmDGfwA)

---

The part `m:m+n-2` of the functions is actually sequence ΔT - vector starting from `n` to `m+n-2`.
We subtract 2 to get the correct number - one value is added as the `1` which starts the triangle sequence and second is added by the fact we include both ends of the vector.
We could subtract 1 and get 0-based indexing but since MATLAB is 1-base indexed I decided to stay consistent and subtract 2 as it doesn't change the length of the code.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 19 bytes

```
f:{1+y*(y+x+x-1)%2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82q2lC7UkujUrtCu0LXUFPVqPZ/WrSuibVZ7H8A)

-2 thanks to tip of @Razetime

Comment: you can move the +1 to the left

Comment: @Razetime thanks

Comment: `y*(y+x+x-1)%2` could be `y%2%y+x+x-1` (assuming `y+x+x-1` is never 0)

Comment: or the whole thing could be `{1+/x+!y}`

Comment: also, `f:` is usually not counted in the byte score

Answer (score 3):

## [Commentator](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Commentator), 44 bytes

```
 {- {-//-}-}
?{-*///{- {-#          /*-}-}-}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PzU3NK0ksyS/6/1@hWheI9PV1a3VrueyrdbX09fXBQsoKcKCvBZLVrf3//7@uCQA)

outputs all entries in the triangle style sequence for n.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 13 bytes

```
1+*+2%~]-~]*]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc7NCsIwDAfw@54iCDK3bnX9WNcWB0PBk@zg2eJBHOrFN9ir10bE5ZBDfiT55xVXPJ@g95BDBQ34VDWHw/l0jIKVTK7nUM@hDLHIxj0HwbaXodqwJx92vsiy@@3xBgE9XDVM4H59g6AIOAS5gLQIYgHVJUjZf9AGgUy0LQK5YTQCSekUAvlDWYxRju7gJ8bSHBT9lfgB)

Based on same formula used by [pajonk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226566/15469) and others.

Returns `m`th element, with 0 indexing.

- `]-~]*]` `m` subtracted from `m*m`...
- `2%~` divided by 2...
- `1+*+` plus `m*n` plus 1

Comment: I don't think this conforms to any of the allowed output method.

Comment: I figured outputting `m+1` instead of `m` wouldn't matter, but I just asked caird to find out.

Comment: @Bubbler caird confirmed my original approach was illegal (though I don't think it should be, since it's the equivalent of 0 indexing for option 1).  A J translation of the closed-form formula turned out to be 1 byte shorter than `1+/\@,(+i.@<:)`, though, so I switched to that.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 21 bytes

```apl
f←{(⍺×(⍺+⍵+⍵-1)÷2)+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P@1R24RqjUe9uw5PB5Haj3q3grCuoebh7Uaa2oa1//8DAA)

Port of my JS answer.

Dyadic function taking \$m\$ on the left and \$n\$ on the right.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 44 bytes

```
(n,m)->Vec(1/(1-x)^3-(2-n)*x/(1-x)^2+O(x^m))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7XyNPJ1dT1y4sNVnDUF/DULdCM85YV8NIN09TqwLKN9L216iIy9XU/J@WX6SRp2CroGuiowBEBUWZeSVAASUFXTsFJR2FNKBhCoYGmkCVAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 44 bytes

```javascript
n=>g=(m,j=1,i=n)=>m--?[j,...g(m,j+i++,i)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchLCoAgFADA6/jwQ0KLCJ4dRFyIqSh@IqPrG81ysn3tcHe6Ht766WfA2VBFJJVllCxhA1SV80NnJoSI/9NEKUtgdm2m62304kXpkQSybkDkAjA/)

> Take a positive integer m and output the first m integers of the "triangle-style" sequence for n.

Simple recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
Ｉ⁺⊘×Ｉη⊕η×⊖η⁻θ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEIyCntFjDIzGnLDVFIyQzN7UYIpyhqaPgmZdclJqbmlcClMrQ1ASKQBS4pCKL6yj4ZuYBzSjUUTDSBAHr//91TbhM/uuW5QAA) Explanation: \$ T'(n, m) = T(m) + (m - 1)(n - 2) \$.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 84 bytes

```
\d+
$*
^,
-,
^-
-11
^1,
-1,
^11

(?=(1*,1)?(1*))1
$2
-(1*)(1*,)\1
-$2
-?,

^$|1+
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HZC7TsNAEEX7@Q6D7LCLdh5xvAVyyU9EFkhQ0FAgSv7dzNkiN44z5@rq/Hz@fn2/nw/z69t5/3iS6SJHkVrkqFJV5dD8lZ8jn2XeX2a9FF32/FoWlcmk8sjb5a5SebEXkWP60yx7fjzPGiX/iGKEE0FciZW4ERvRCW1SHcRBHMRBHMRBHMRBHMQHYiAGYiAGYiAGYiAGYiA2EAVREAVREAVREAVREAVRkJZES6Dlfcvzltctj1vetjxtedk4pJpmiumlllZK6aRyNDKb1YxmM5NZzGD2MnesRQlGEIIPdGADGbhAxTCBbmwjG9eoxjSi8YzmYdk7lZ3OTmmntVPb6e0Ud5o71R1k3RLJMMKJIK7EStyIjejjOOeABEiABEiABEiABEiAcNz@AQ) Link includes test cases. Takes `n,m` as input. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
^,
-,
^-
-11
^1,
-1,
^11
```

Subtract 2 from \$ n \$.

```
(?=(1*,1)?(1*))1
$2
```

Calculate \$ (n - 2)(m - 1) \$ and \$ T(m) \$.

```
-(1*)(1*,)\1
-$2
-?,
```

Take the sum.

```
^$|1+
$.&
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 19 bytes

```raku
{[\+] [1,|[$_..*]]}
```

```
          [$_..*]    -- generate infinite list from topic variable $_ (implicity set when calling fn with 1 param) to infinity
         |[$_..*]    -- flatten once
      [1,|[$_..*]    -- put the flattened version into a list with 1 at the front
 [\+] [1,|[$_..*]]   -- triangular reduce on addition
{[\+] [1,|[$_..*]]}  -- put in a block
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVDRSuRAEHyfr2gHkY0mMTOZSTIse/p6cH@QjRI0C4E1rpt4ILv76Juf4P3c/chaHTMgxyGkQ3d1VXUlm2a7zo4PL3S2ogUdd@XyoqJShfvy9DaOz6vqwMvroemH6K7um6jebkFct13Txw/1Zhb9oCVPtBM0wnG/WbfD7FISVnK/lyHJy6BMQlJsGN83zYaF5/HPbgjEIZgLsXrc/nsD4tmy7UK6fnwegtGdg9Rdj/OrWdsF5Y1Kqjnwvn4hyZuyosViFKDbMRL/avuBmqffI0pXVyT/vr9KOjlB8@dNHuRcHI6R4XMqpChFZagC5aYqJgw7JaLUUzXKoOxU5hPDCpNKRKQ907P1Z48HXLgqdnQiUhMxGR80wDP2QMFLA9GFoGSi8Tha5Oh5BlcD0Qib5oK83TckbDJBPuD/zgEFZjBbK8h/9NfcYIGRAjKYLZsYQf5P2smQz2KVshizRWXo81SkzpsCK5irx5xg64RlzNXO8g0OWRQiKyZJ5jhFwUx@5fxRlq00x3HAbD4GcsJ4jQGJN8rwy3F@lqSJYTEww99lMvcB)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
r+Σ)
```

Similar as the Jelly, Vyxal, and 05AB1E answers.
Inputs are a 0-based \$m\$ and \$n\$, and it outputs the \$m\$'th triangle-style number.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/79I@9xizf//DRR0TbgMQYQRiDAGESYgwlJB1xhEGIEIQyBhAMQgGiQAkgEpMbYEEmYWIJ4FAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
r     # Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) first input-integer)
 +    # Add the second (implicit) input-integer to each value in this list
  Σ   # Sum this list
   )  # Increase it by 1
      # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>80</s> 71 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input_m][S N
S _Duplicate_m][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S S S T  S N
_Push_2][T  S T S _Integer-divide][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input_n][T    S S S _Add][T   S S N
_Multiply][S S S T  N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][T   N
S T _Print_as_integer_to_STDOUT]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QQDIAgIgB0iAGApAFoiBrAYiAVYJVggkFTj//7fkMrYEAA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Formula used:**

Given a 0-based \$m\$ and \$n\$, it outputs the \$m\$'th triangular-style number with the following formula:

$$T(n,m) = m\left(\left\lfloor\frac{m-1}{2}\right\rfloor + n\right) + 1$$

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 88 bytes

```sql
SELECT-sum(~number+~(1/~number)*~-~-@)over(order by number)FROM spt_values
WHERE'P'=type
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1507982/triangle-style-sequences)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 20 bytes

```rust
|n,m|(m+2*n-1)*m/2+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJdb5tAEHy/X7HxQwQJUDg@DHbjh/6EPvQlqiLLPiRUOFM40qgxv92dhaO21CoSC3ezs7Oza3dDby5Dr6g3x82mOm02X4byq9oft6LU1Owr7bj0TrUyVD5dztprzk7zKB@0H7kPzSf5GF2ItoKoPHVUV1pRpa9aOLBAUJ8OP/iDfM964NOk6WiP1FurDkYdXXqidt/16qXS7WCce6YHg/7V7VvHdbdiqmq7Sps7Z/U@kr@jlUfa3U4JNtBw9zAIotD2mLt0qh9qA/kS/ZpFiagqUbEjkP/KerRytzRawrUZErOK7Ua073vVmRf1886ZM9dJnhtkaeir3@q75Y9X87WG4mrCRzEK3vPt2Dz1hu5707k8oVPF0vumDp/x3d2urhkMVTzUtKa@rSvjrKad2JaONYo5TaDVm8EvsGwzMF3V4DM1vsG9j2psD15R0AA5v55f/1Fwg8OprrEGx520XDFe/IR9RR75MSJD5IjCRm4x5CLhxwtVIhJEaiOZMaRwi0Lhy4W5sOV8xgMuVCNWLIQfWWI4PTgAz1gDAS0JROYCf4OZxtdJYo0z38GVQCTMxmtBi9wHJGQyQYvB/7UDCizBPU0FLUPf@gYLjBhQgnvKIomgZZOpFeS2SMVcjHuKyHBexyIuFlFgOXPl5BNsGXIZc2WRcg82meciy21JVrCLnJn8WvNQKUtJtlMAS9eToUIkS00CEmeihF8F@@eSOEy4GFjCcyVZ8Qc)

Takes \$n\$ and \$m\$ and returns the \$m\$-th integer (0-based indexing).

Uses the straightforward formula.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
M.u++NGYUtH1
```

Takes \$n\$ and \$m\$, and returns the first \$m\$ integers of the sequence for \$n\$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/31evVFvbzz0ytMTD8H96vImCocH/f/kFJZn5ecX/dVMA)